# Calculate Actual execution of query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

Could someone please suggest how can we calculate the actual execution of the query. With out IO operations.

currently, I am using following approch:

```
variable n number
exec :n := dbms_utility.get_time
PROMPT The time consumed with Function Call
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
variable n number
exec :n := dbms_utility.get_time
set term off;

  select   -- My Select Query

SET TERM ON;
exec dbms_output.put_line( dbms_utility.get_time - :n )
```

Is this the correct way of calculating the query execution time?

Comment: "set timing on" is much easier

Comment: Actually the select query resulting very huge data, In my understanding IO operation is taking more time then retrieving from database. 

WIth SET TERM OFF i could not able to find the Time consumed.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you to use SQLTrace.

before running you query:

```
     ALTER SESSION SET sql_trace = true;
     ALTER SESSION SET tracefile_identifier = [sqltrace_identifier_which_will_be_included_into_output_filename];
```

then run your query and set trace back to OFF:

```
     ALTER SESSION SET sql_trace = false;
```

now you have a trace file generated. Look for trace file in USER_DUMP_DEST folder.
But it is not human-friendly.
Use tkprof utility to convert it to readable format (replace "input.trc" with your file name. your filename contains identifier you set into tracefile_identifier parameter):

```
     tkprof input.trc output.prf
```

Read output.prf file and enjoy :)

Some detailed explanations:

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL_Trace 
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/TKProf